# Store paragraph of text in variable C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that takes user's input and stores the entire paragraph in a variable. However, if the user enters: "Hello, this is some text." It only returns "Hello" Can anyone help?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class GetText
{
public:

    string text;

    void userText()
    {
        cout << "Please type a message: ";
        cin >> text;
    }

    void to_string()
    {
        cout << "\n" << "User's Text: " << "\n" << text << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    GetText test;
    test.userText();
    test.to_string();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin` doesn't care about spaces or new lines.. use `while (cin >> some_string_stream)` or `getline`

Comment: @Brandon for some reason, I get an error message when using some_string_stream or getline. Do I need to import something? Secondly, how would I store this in the text variable?

Comment: You need to include the <string> header

Comment: Are you SURE it returns `"Hello"` and not `"Hello,"` ?

Comment: @Brandon: The relevant thing isn't `cin`, but `operator>>(std::istream&, std::string&)`.  All streams act this way, not just `std::cin`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I wasn't sure if all streams did that. That's for the clarification. OP you can use.. http://ideone.com/B76nyQ  The problem with both is figuring out when to stop reading.. `getline` should be easier since you can break out of the while loop. For the second example, I'm not sure how to break it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read an entire line from user input:

```
std::string text;
std::getline(std::cin, text);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e22315bee8e88e9)

Answer (score 2):

When getting values using cin, the input stream treats spaces as a string split delimiter by default. Instead, you should use std::getline(), which reads the input until it detects a new line character.

However, like I said above, std::getline() reads the input until it detects a new line character, meaning that it can only read one line at a time. So in order to read an entire paragraph with multiple lines, you'll need to use a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> //For getline()

using namespace std;

// Creating class
class GetText
{
public:

    string text;
    string line; //Using this as a buffer

    void userText()
    {
        cout << "Please type a message: ";

        do
        {
            getline(cin, line);
            text += line;
        }
        while(line != "");
    }

    void to_string()
    {
        cout << "\n" << "User's Text: " << "\n" << text << endl;
    }
     };

     int main() {

    GetText test;
    test.userText();
    test.to_string();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This code reads the stream line by line, storing the current line in the string variable "line". I use the variable "line" as a buffer between the input stream and the variable "text", which I store the entire paragraph in using the += operator. It reads the input until the current line is an empty line.